# Ignore � (non-UTF-8 characters) in email attachment or strip them from the attachment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, actionmailer, email-attachments

Users of our application are able to upload plain text files. These files might then be added as attachments to outgoing `ActionMailer` emails. Recently an attempt to send said email resulted in an `invalid byte sequence in UTF-8` error. The email was not sent. This symbol, �, appears throughout the offending attachment.

We're using `ActionMailer` so although it ought to go without saying, here's representative code for the attachment action within the mailer class's method:

`attachments['file-name.jpg'] = File.read('file-name.jpg')`

From a business standpoint we don't care about the content of these text files. Ideally I'd like for our application to ignore the content and simply attach them to emails.

Is it possible to somehow tell `Rails` / `ActionMailer` to ignore the formatting? Or should I parse the incoming text file, stripping out non-UTF-8 characters?

I did search through like questions here on Stack Overflow but nothing addressed the problem I'm currently facing.

Edit: I did call `#readlines` on the file in a Rails console and found that the black diamond is a representation of `\xA0`. This is likely a non-breaking space in Latin1 (ISO 8859-1).

Comment: Please give your code where you read your text attachments (from HDD or database or whatever). If `str` is your string which contains the attachment at some point in time, please tell us what `str.encoding` is. Show us the line of code that attaches the string to the mail.

Comment: It's just typical code for attaching a file to an ActionMailer email: `mail.attachments[file.file_name.to_s] = File.read(path_to_file)`.

Answer (score 1):

If Ruby is having problems reading the file and corrupting the characters during the read then try using [`File.binread`](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/IO#binread-class_method). *`File.binread` is inherited from `IO`*

```
...
  attachments['attachment.txt'] = File.binread('/path/to/file')
...
```

If your file already has corrupted characters then you can either find some process to 'uncorrupt' them, *which is not fun*, or strip them using by re-encoding from `ASCII-8bit` to `UTF-8` stripping out the invalid characters.

```
...
  attachments['attachment.txt'] = File.binread('/path/to/file')
    .encode('utf-8', 'binary', invalid: :replace, undef: :replace)
...
```

([`String#scrub` does this](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/String#scrub%21-instance_method) but since you can't read it in as `UTF-8` then you cant use it.)

Comment: Symptoms remain unchanged using your proposed solution. Email is unsent. What is `#binread` supposed to do? I don't see it as an available method for the `File` class in Ruby 2.2.1, which is what I'm currently using.

Comment: It gets inherited from `IO` and basically just reads the file as an `ASCII-8bit` binary file, but it would appear that the file already has corrupt characters. Which is probably throwing off the `Base64` encoding process. I'll add more to the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, that also didn't solve the problem. And so since you say it's available on `String` I attempted to use `#scrub` in a console: `"Text text text� text text".scrub` results in `"Text text text� text text"` (the diamond remains, it's persistent).

Comment: `�`  is actually a legitimate Unicode character so it won't remove it. But most readers replace unrecognized invalid Unicode characters with that character.

Comment: Manually removing each occurrence of � will permit for successful attachment and email transmission, I tried that immediately and so I know those characters are at fault. If it's a legitimate Unicode character then what's a developer to do?

Comment: This is like crazy Ruby 1.8 type stuff I had to recall and think about sorry. Most of these problems are solved, but I don't think I've ever had to problem with reading a file with invalid characters.

Comment: Man... That File.binread saved my project! On AWS server that was the only way that I could attach an PDF here on my project.

Answer (score 0):

With your edit, this seems pretty clear to me:

1. The file on your filesystem is encoded in latin1.
2. File.read uses the standard ruby encoding by default. If LANG contains something like "en_GB.utf8", `File.read` will associate the string with utf-8 encoding. You can verify this by logging the value of `str.encoding` (where `str` is the value of `File.read`).
3. `File.read` does not actually verify the encoding, it only slurps in the bytes and slaps on the encoding (like `force_encoding`).
4. Later, in ActionMailer, something wants to transcode the string, for whatever reason, and that fails as expected (and with the result you are noticing).

If your text files are encoded in latin1, then use `File.read(path, encoding: Encoding::ISO_8859_1)`. This way, it may work. Let us know if it doesn't...

Comment: `File.read(file).encoding` yields `#<Encoding:UTF-8>` Issuing `file -i <filename>` in a terminal results in `charset=iso-8859-1`. Your proposed code does not work, the email still is not transmitted. But even if it did work I could not use it as a solution as I have no control over the documents which are uploaded. As I mentioned originally, ideally our application would simply ignore the content of these files.

Comment: I truly do appreciate the help, by the way!

Comment: Sure, np - encoding is often a very confusing issue. The closest you can get to "binary" in ruby is the `Encoding::ASCII_8BIT`, as far as I know (which is the encoding `binread` would give you). But as you tested already, that also doesn't seem to work. We would have to find out at which place `ActionMailer` insists to treat the bytes as `utf-8` and tries to transcode or verify the encoding. Though I admit I am confused why it happens; I mean your code is ripped straight from the `ActionMailer` docs, and there they use it to transfer a PNG (won't get much more binary than that...).

Comment: I think we'll probably check for the content-type at upload and replace anything not `utf-8` right then. It's come up maybe three times in five years but in those cases it's a confusing show-stopper for users.

Answer (score 0):

When reading the file at time of attachment, I can use the following syntax.

```
mail.attachments[file.file_name.to_s] = File.read(path_to_file).force_encoding("BINARY").gsub(0xA0.chr,"")
```

The important addition is the following, which goes after the call to `File.read(...)`:

`.force_encoding("BINARY").gsub(0xA0.chr,"")`

The stripping and encoding ought to be done at time of file upload to our system, so this answer isn't the resolution. It's a short-term band-aid.